# Send extra email at registration

Tags: email, magento, registration

I  have created a module which sets the customer group at the time of registration based on post value. I need to send the email about this to the customer with the registration email also. Please suggest how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an email template from `System->Transnational Emails`.
2. Use the below code to send the email

   $templateId = your template id;

   $sender = Array('name' => 'Sender Name',
           'email' => 'Sender Email Id');

   $email = 'Receiver Email Id';
   // $vars contains all variables details need to be display in email
   $vars = Array('customer_email'=>'Customer Email Id',
       'customer_name'=>'Customer Name'
   );
   $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
   $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
   Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
           ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, null, $vars, $storeId);
   $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
3. Modify the above details as per your requirement.
4. Done

Comment: thats work perfect
can you please tell me about
$vars , can i use this in email template for displaying information

Comment: YES, You need to write like {{var customer_email}} in that email template.